# How to find the centre of these sometimes-overlapping circles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to find the centre-point of some "blobs" in an image using OpenCV with Python. 
I'm having a bit of trouble with it, and would truly appreciate any help or insight :)

My current method is to: get the contours of the images, overlay ellipses on those, use the blob detector to find the centre of each of these.
This works fairly well, but occasionally I have extraneous blobs that I need to ignore, and sometimes the blobs are touching each-other.

Here's an example of when it goes well:
**Good source image:**
[image: Good source image]
**After extracting contours:**
[image: After extracting contours]
**With the blobs detected:**
[image: With the blobs detected]

And when it goes poorly (you can see that it's incorrectly overlayed an ellipse over three blobs, and detected one that I don't want):
**Bad source image:**
[image: Bad source image]
**After extracting contours:**
[image: After extracting contours]
**With the blobs detected:**
[image: With the blobs detected]

This is the code I currently use. I'm unsure of any other option.

```
def process_and_detect(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 50, 150, 0)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    drawn_img = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
    min_area = 50
    min_ellipses = []
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) >= min_area:
            ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
            cv2.ellipse(drawn_img,ellipse,(0,255,0),-1)
    plot_img(drawn_img, size=12)

    # Change thresholds
    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.filterByColor = True
    params.blobColor = 255
    params.filterByCircularity = True
    params.minCircularity = 0.75
    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 150
    # Set up the detector
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

    # Detect blobs.
    keypoints = detector.detect(drawn_img)
    for k in keypoints:
        x = round(k.pt[0])
        y = round(k.pt[1])
        line_length = 20
        cv2.line(img, (x-line_length, y), (x+line_length, y), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(img, (x, y-line_length), (x, y+line_length), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    plot_img(img, size=12)
```

Thank you so much for reading this far, I sincerely hope someone can help me out, or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know beforehand how many blobs there will be? Should all blobs be similar in size or is it possible that you might have a blob the size of those 3 combined blobs? This pipeline is very redundant as the `SimpleBlobDetector` does it's own set of thresholding and contour detection operations. You already have most of the work done before applying the `SimpleBlobDetector`.

Comment: The blob's I'm working with are the outputs of a neural network, so I know the number of blobs during training, but not at test-time - which is a critical time.
It is very unlikely that there'll ever be a blob the size of 3 combined, but they do fluctuate a little in size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Blob detector

Currently, your implementation is redundant. From the [`SimpleBlobDetector()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector):

> The class implements a simple algorithm for extracting blobs from an image:
>
> 1. Convert the source image to binary images by applying thresholding with several thresholds from minThreshold (inclusive) to maxThreshold (exclusive) with distance thresholdStep between neighboring thresholds.
> 2. Extract connected components from every binary image by findContours() and calculate their centers.
> 3. Group centers from several binary images by their coordinates. Close centers form one group that corresponds to one blob, which is controlled by the minDistBetweenBlobs parameter.
> 4. From the groups, estimate final centers of blobs and their radiuses and return as locations and sizes of keypoints.

So you're implementing part of the steps already, which might give some unexpected behavior. You could try playing with the parameters to see if you can figure out some that work for you (try creating [trackbars](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#createtrackbar) to play with the parameters and get live results of your algorithm with different blob detector parameters).

## Modifying your pipeline

However, you've already got most of your own pipeline written, so you can easily remove the blob detector and implement your own algorithm. If you simply drop your threshold a bit, you can easily get clearly marked circles, and then blob detection is as simple as contour detection. If you have a separate contour for each blob, then you can calculate the centroid of the contour with [`moments()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments). For example:

```
def process_and_detect(img_path):

    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
    line_length = 20
    for c in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) >= min_area:
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            x = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            y = int(M['m01']/M['m00']) 
            cv2.line(img, (x-line_length, y), (x+line_length, y), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(img, (x, y-line_length), (x, y+line_length), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

[image: Detected centroids]

## Getting more involved

This same pipeline can be used to automatically loop through threshold values so you don't have to guess and hardcode those values. Since the blobs all seem roughly the same size, you can loop through until all contours have roughly the same area. You could do this for e.g. by finding the median contour size, defining some percentage of that median size above and below that you'll allow, and checking if all the contours detected fit in those bounds.

Here's an animated `gif` of what I mean. Notice that the `gif` stops once the contours are separated:

[image: Contour areas shrinking until similar]

Then you can simply find the centroids of those separated contours. Here's the code:

```
def process_and_detect(img_path):

    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    for thresh_val in range(0, 255):

        # threshold and detect contours
        thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, thresh_val, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,
                                    cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

        # filter contours by area
        min_area = 50
        filtered_contours = [c for c in contours
                             if cv2.contourArea(c) >= min_area]
        area_contours = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in filtered_contours]

        # acceptable deviation from median contour area
        median_area = np.median(area_contours)
        dev = 0.3
        lowerb = median_area - dev*median_area
        upperb = median_area + dev*median_area

        # break when all contours are within deviation from median area
        if ((area_contours > lowerb) & (area_contours < upperb)).all():
            break

    # draw center location of blobs
    line_length = 8
    cross_color = (255, 0, 0)
    for c in filtered_contours:
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        x = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        cv2.line(img, (x-line_length, y), (x+line_length, y), cross_color, 2)
        cv2.line(img, (x, y-line_length), (x, y+line_length), cross_color, 2)
```

[image: Centroids found]

Note that here I looped through all possible threshold values with `range(0, 255)` to give `0, 1, ..., 254` but really you could start higher and skip through a few values at a time with, say, `range(50, 200, 5)` to get `50, 55, ..., 195` which would of course be much faster.

Comment: Using several thresholds to separate the blobs is indeed a good way. Grouping the centers is not the only option. You can consider the centers obtained when there is a good separation, so that the inner part of the blob is more symmetrical. I also guess that an accurate measurement of the radius is out of reach, as the touching blobs are actually no more circular. (Maybe with a robust fitting of a spherical surface on the intensity map.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree with your watershed approach too, and it was what I would have suggested if OP didn't already have an almost working pipeline. It looks like in OP's pics that the blobs will all be similar in size, so you could easily loop through multiple thresholds and `break` whenever all contours bigger than `min_area` are close to the median sized contour.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well you inspired me to loop through threshold values with this same approach. Seems to work well!

Comment: Hehe, looping through all threshold values is... the watershed!

Comment: @YvesDaoust indeed! I just thought it would be fun to approach it manually with the code that OP brought to the table.

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" approach for such blob-splitting problem is by means of the watershed transform. It can be applied on the binary image, using a transform distance, or directly on the grayscale image.

Oversegmentation problems can make it tricky, but it seems that your case will not suffer from that.

To find the center, I would usually recommend a weighted average of the pixel coordinates to get a noise reduction effect, but in this case I would probably go for the location of the maximum intensity, which won't be influenced by the deformation of the shape.

Here is what you get with a grayscale watershed (the region intensity is the average). Contrary to what I initially thought, there is some fragmentation due to irregularities in the blobs

[image]

You can improve with a little of lowpass filtering before segmentation.

[image]