# Irregular area measurement of each crystals in an image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, opencv

I am trying to find area of each crystals in an image. For crystals separation i have used watershed algorithm. the results i have also attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldejb.png) 
I'm attempting to do some image analysis using OpenCV in python, but I think the images themselves are going to be quite tricky, and I've never done anything like this before so I want to sound out my logic and maybe get some ideas/practical code to achieve what I want to do, before I invest a lot of time going down the wrong path.

This thread comes pretty close to what I want to achieve, and in my opinion, uses an image that should be even harder to analyse than mine. I'd be interested in the size of those coloured blobs though, rather than their distance from the top left. I've also been following this code, though I'm not especially interested in a reference object (the dimensions in pixels alone would be enough for now and can be converted afterwards).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('ESlPT.png')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 2)
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Morphological gradient

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7, 7))
gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(blur, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
cv2.imshow('Morphological gradient', gradient)
cv2.waitKey()
# Binarize gradient

lowerb = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upperb = np.array([15, 15, 15])
binary = cv2.inRange(gradient, lowerb, upperb)
cv2.imshow('Binarized gradient', binary)
cv2.waitKey()
# Flood fill from the edges to remove edge crystals

for row in range(h):
    if binary[row, 0] == 255:
        cv2.floodFill(binary, None, (0, row), 0)
    if binary[row, w-1] == 255:
        cv2.floodFill(binary, None, (w-1, row), 0)

for col in range(w):
    if binary[0, col] == 255:
        cv2.floodFill(binary, None, (col, 0), 0)
    if binary[h-1, col] == 255:
        cv2.floodFill(binary, None, (col, h-1), 0)

cv2.imshow('Filled binary gradient', binary)
cv2.waitKey()
# Cleaning up mask

foreground = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
foreground = cv2.morphologyEx(foreground, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('Cleanup up crystal foreground mask', foreground)
cv2.waitKey()
# Creating background and unknown mask for labeling

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (17, 17))
background = cv2.dilate(foreground, kernel, iterations=3)
unknown = cv2.subtract(background, foreground)
cv2.imshow('Background', background)
cv2.waitKey()
# Watershed

markers = cv2.connectedComponents(foreground)[1]
markers += 1  # Add one to all labels so that background is 1, not 0
markers[unknown==255] = 0  # mark the region of unknown with zero
markers = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
# Assign the markers a hue between 0 and 179

hue_markers = np.uint8(179*np.float32(markers)/np.max(markers))
blank_channel = 255*np.ones((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
marker_img = cv2.merge([hue_markers, blank_channel, blank_channel])
marker_img = cv2.cvtColor(marker_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('Colored markers', marker_img)

cv2.waitKey()
#Label the original image with the watershed markers

labeled_img = img.copy()
labeled_img[markers>1] = marker_img[markers>1]  # 1 is background color
labeled_img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.5, labeled_img, 0.5, 0)
cv2.imshow('watershed_result.png', labeled_img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

nter code here

[result after applying marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrtYD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Irregular shape detection and measurement in python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036172/irregular-shape-detection-and-measurement-in-python-opencv)